# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My new ASP.NET MVC Web Application works on my development workstation, but does not run on my web server...

---

## Server Error in '/' Application.

---

### Configuration Error

**Description:** An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

**Parser Error Message:** Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

**Source Error:**

```
Line 44:         <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
Line 45:         <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
Line 46:         <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
Line 47:         <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
Line 48:         <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
```

**Source File:** C:\inetpub\www.example.org\web.config    **Line:** 46

**Assembly Load Trace:** The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.

```
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

---

**Version Information:** Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053

---

Do I need to install the *AspNetMVCBeta-setup.msi* on the server?  Or is there a different installer for servers?

[image]

Answer (score 216, accepted):

I just wrote a blog post addressing this. You could install ASP.NET MVC on your server OR you can follow the [steps here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx).

---

**EDIT:** (by jcolebrand) I went through this link, then had the same issue as [Victor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/653855/victor-juri) [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267006/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-mvc/5481834#5481834), so I suggest you also add these:

```
* Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
* System.Web.Razor
* System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
* System.Web.WebPages.Razor
```

Comment: Note: When you have MVC4 (beta currently) installed, you'll want to grab v1.0 of those DLLs, you'll also want to grab System.Web.Helpers (at least I needed to).

Comment: -1 Your post that you link to, does not explain how to get the Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure to the web server via the Publishing mechanism.  Having to install things on a server directly, kind of sux.

Comment: with visual studio 2010 this has become much easier as explained here: http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/06/adding-mvc-dependencies-to-project-for.html

Comment: or here if you're not using Web Deploy http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/05/mvc3-deploy-could-not-load-file-or.html

Comment: I had to hose the bin folder and then Publish again, that is, if you're not using Deploy Package.

Answer (score 42):

I ran into the same issue as sgriffinusa.
In addition to the references Phil's article suggests: http://www.haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx .  I added these:

```
* Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
* System.Web.Razor
* System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
* System.Web.WebPages.Razor
```

Godaddy Deployment worked perfectly. Turn custom errors off and add references to correct the errors. That should lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 26):

Installing MVC directly on your web server is one option, as then the assemblies will be installed in the GAC. You can also bin deploy the assemblies, which might help keep your server clear of pre-release assemblies until a final release is available.

Phil Haack posted a nice article a couple days ago about how to deploy MVC along with your app, so it's not necessary to install directly:

http://www.haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx

Answer (score 25):

I ran into this same issue trying to deploy my MVC3 Razor web application on GoDaddy shared hosting.  There are some additional .dlls that need to be referenced.  Details here: http://paulmason.biz/?p=108

Basically you need to add references to the following in addition to the ones listed in @Haacked's post and set them to deploy locally as described.

- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
- System.Web.Razor
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor

Comment: Thanks man, after manually adding the reference and then deploy them locally it did fix the problem for MVC3!

Comment: Same thing here.  Good guidance on adding those additional DLLs.  Thanks!

Comment: Same thing here. Not on GoDaddy but on my company server, so this must be a mere generel case.

Answer (score 13):

In VS2010, right click the project in the Solution Explorer and select 'Add Deployable Dependencies'. Then check the MVC related check boxes in the following dialog.

This creates a '_bin_deployableAssemblies' folder in the project which contains all the .dll files mentioned in other answers. I believe these get copied to the bin folder when creating a deployment package.

Answer (score 12):

**Quick & Simple Solution:** I faced this problem with Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.3 and after going through all these threads I found a simplest solution.

Just follow steps:

1. Open NuGet Package Manager in Visual studio for your project
2. Search for Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
3. When found, change action to Uninstall and Uninstall it
4. Once done, install it again and try it now

This will automatically fix all issues with references. 
See image below:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Simple fix. In VS2010, right click on your MVC project, select "Add Deployable Dependencies...", select the the options you want and click ok

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue and added all the assembly that they said but still got the same error.

turns out you need to make the "**Specific Version**" = False.

[image: Specific version should be false.]

Comment: Alternatively you should switch 'Copy Local' to 'True' if it is not enabled,

Answer (score 6):

We want to add it because we are making a class library that uses it.

For me it is here...

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies`

Answer (score 3):

If your NOT using a hosting provider, and you have access to the server to install ... Then install the MVC 3 update tools, do that... it will save you hours of problems on a windows 2003 server / IIS6 machine.  ,  I commented on this page here   [Nuget.Core.dll version number mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831785/problem-deploying-nuget-server-with-deployable-dependencies/6529145#6529145)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the Haack post, Hanselman also has a similar post.  [BIN Delploying ASP.NET MVC 3 with Razor to a Windows Server without MVC installed](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx)

For me, the "Copy Local = true" solution was insufficient because my Website's project references did not include all the dlls that were missing.  As Scott mentions in his post, I also needed to get additional dlls from the following folder on my development box: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies.  The error message informed me which dll was missing (System.Web.Infrastructure, System.Web.Razor, etc.) I continued to add each missing dll, one by one, until it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I've did a "Update-Package –reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" to fix it in Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 3):

An important consideration is the web.config file, Some packages can mangle your binding redirects causing havoc (the rogue package was in house package that I did not remove the web.config from the package or making sure the web.config in in the package doesn't have any binding redirects. For example by removing the duplicate and incorrect node resolves this

```
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>


                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0"/>
                <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930"/>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2"/>


                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="SimpleInjector" publicKeyToken="984cb50dea722e99" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.2.0" newVersion="3.3.2.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="HtmlAgilityPack" publicKeyToken="bd319b19eaf3b43a" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.4.9.5" newVersion="1.4.9.5"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
```

by removing lines 8 to 24 fixes the build.

Answer (score 2):

Also check the version of the assembly in the web.config inside your **Views folder** and make sure it matches.  I sometimes forget there is a 2nd web.config in that location.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with a bunch of assembly files after moving the project to another solution.

For me, the `web.config` file was trying to add this assembly:

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

Thought the reference in the project was pointing towards version `3.0.0.0` (click on the reference and scroll to the bottom of the properties). Hence I just changed the reference version in the `web.config` file.

I don´t know if this was just a bug of some sort. The problem with adding all the other references was that the references appeared in the config file but it wasn't actually referenced at all in the project (inside the solution explorer) and the needed files were not copied with the rest of the project files, probably due to not being `"copy local = true"`

Now, I wasn´t able to find these assemblies in the addable assemblies (by right clicking the reference and trying to add them from the assemblies or extensions). Instead I created a new MVC solution which added all the assemblies and references I needed, and finding them under the new projects references in the solution explorer and finding their path in the properties window for the reference.

Then I just copied the libraries I needed into the other project and referenced them.

Answer (score 1):

After trying everything and still failing this was my solution:
i remembered i had and error last updating the MVC version in my Visual studio so i run the project from another Visual studio (different computer) and than uploaded the dll-s and it worked.
maybe it will help someone...

Answer (score 0):

I am using Jenkins with .net projects and had troubles with MVC 4 references.

I finallys solved my issue by using a .Net reference search engine functionality based on the registry using :

"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\AssemblyFoldersEx"

You can create subkey et set the default key to "c:\myreferenceedir" for example.

It saved me with MVC versions and also ASP.net Web pages.

Usefull to add references to the "Add Reference Dialog"

http://dhakshinamoorthy.wordpress.com/2011/12/04/how-to-register-your-net-assembly-in-gac-and-make-it-show-in-add-reference-dialog/

Answer (score 0):

I added "Microsoft ASP.NET Razor" using Manage NuGet Packages.

With Add References, for some reason, I only had System.Web.Helpers 1.0.0 and 2.0.0... but not 3.0.0.

Another option, that worked form me was to delete the references to System.Web.Mvc and System.Web.Http... then re-add them browing to the package locations in the csproj file (you can most easily edit the project with a text editor):

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Http">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll</HintPath>

<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Others have mentioned, add these refernces to visual studios with `Copy Local` set to `true`. ( I also had to add `System.Web.Webpages`)

```
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
System.Web.Razor
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
System.Web.WebPages.Razor
System.Web.Webpages
```