# Razor pages in MVC are giving a compile error with System.Web.Helpers not being found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

My razor view is failing to compile with the following error:

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Helpers' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I have System.Web.Helpers added as a reference to my project, so I am not sure what else I need to do.  I have also tried a clean rebuild after adding the reference, and no change.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this project upgraded from a previous version of MVC?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267006/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-mvc/4801390#4801390

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Aha figured it out.  I needed to add

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

To the `<assemblies>` section of web.config!

Comment: can you tell me how it add automatically into the web config file?

Comment: I don't see an `assembly` section in my web.config. Is there a sample file?

Comment: Put the line under <configuration><system.web><compilation><assemblies><add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

Answer (score 3):

Web.config line should go here:

```
  <configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
          <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```