# An MVC3 project is looking for 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0,

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, xval

I'm deploying an MVC3 project that began life in the old days of xVal. I think that's the root of this error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I have the same webapp running correctly on the production server - a win08 (pre-R2) box that served the v1 version of the app. Now I'm moving to a newly provisioned R2 box and find that any page referencing xVal is tossing the above error.

Is there a way to transfer the older dll(s) without digging thru the asp.net/mvc site for an old distro? I'd really like to avoid touching any bits of the validation system right now.

thx

ADDENDUM: Initially the pointer to Phil Haack's post seemed to solve my problem - but re-deployed today and having the same issue with this additional info.

I'm using ELMAH to log the app's errors and the source being reported to ELMAH might offer a clue. Instead of the SOURCE property being something like 'NHIBERNATE' or 'SYSTEM' or my assembly's name i'm seeing 'App_Web_b1pe5vbs'. The log has a handful of these oddly named Sources. Any thing to see here?

thx

Comment: This is probably a duplicate... check this post, it should solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267006/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-mvc

Comment: This is the direct link to the post by Phil Haack on the subject: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx

Answer (score 2):

in vs2010 you could now right click on the MVC3 project, click on "Add Deployable Dependencies" and select ASP.net MVC checkbox, it will add required assemblies in _bin_deployableAssemblies folder.

Comment: Sorry to un-answer this - turns out the problem returned the next time I deployed something. editing my OP.