# Issue with System.Web.Mvc reference

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on some background processes for a MVC4 WebApplication. I've made a separate application, independent of the Web Role to do so. I added the System.Web.Mvc reference into a Class Library so I could work with SelectListItem's and other Mvc related items on the service level (which the workers will use).

However I keep getting this error anytime the application executes:

> "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'System.Web.Mvc,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'"

The odd part is, if I debug it has no issue what so ever!
I've searched some and tried setting the CopyLocal and SpecificVersionNum to True. But that didn't work.

Now in the Web Roles web.config I use this assembly binding:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

To ensure I avoid errors like this. Do I have do something similar for the Class Library? If so how? Last I checked putting configs on class libraries was a HUGE no no.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267006/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-mvc

Comment: I followed the suggestion made there and added the other references but I am still getting this error.