# Could not load file or assembly System.Web.Mvc when calling Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, runtime-error

I am using Windsor Castle IoC in my Web API-based project.

The project is getting built successfully.But while calling the API, I am getting the below error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I didn't get any useful links yet & not sure what code snippet should I attach here. Please forgive me for this.

In case any thing needed please let me know, I will provide.

What is the cause of the error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Will it help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267006/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-mvc

Comment: It's saying it can't find the DLL in the output folder, at least not one with the right version and public key. Try to at least Clean Solution -> Rebuild Solution

Comment: @Prisoner, Already checked & rechecked but not useful to me

Comment: @juunas, done. still same error

Comment: Have you used fusion logs to check the assembly bindings when the project starts up?

Comment: Check to see if it's on your machine. usually in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\FUSLOGVW.exe"   something like that?